# Setting UISlider value on app start

Tags: ios, reset, uislider

I have a `UISlider` with values from 0 to 1.

The problem is if I slide it to a value, then close the app and reopen the app, the UISlider will stay on the value set by the sliding. Basically it remembers the value that it was last on.

I've tried some code to set it so that it can always be on 0 when the ViewController appears but it doesn't work. I tried this code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
mySlider.value = 0;
```

And I've also tried this:

```
[mySlider setValue:0]
```

But neither of them work.

How I can have the UISlider always on 0 when the app opens ?

Comment: what do you mean by close the app, sending it to background  or killing.

Comment: I believe he means sending to background, because killing it and re-opening the ViewController would call viewDidLoad again, so no problem.

Comment: Yeah, I meant sending it to the background, not killing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your code (`[mySlider setValue:0]`) in `viewWillAppear` if you don't want to see the slider value change, in `viewDidAppear` if you want to see it change.

`viewDidLoad` is only called when you create the view, it's not called when you display it after it has been loaded (for example, exiting the app and comming back, comming back from a push/pop in the navigation of a `UINavigationController`, etc.).

*Note you can use this method : `[mySlider setValue:0 Animated:YES];` if you want to see the animation.*

Comment: Thank you for your help I appreciate it. I may be doing something wrong but if I open the app the first time, it works. Putting the app in the background and reopening doesn't fire this viewDidAppear again. The slider value remains what it was last left on before putting the app in the background. Any ideas?

Comment: Logging inside viewDidAppear only works when the app is first opened, it doesn't log again after sending app to background and opening again. `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [switchSlider setValue:1 animated:YES];
    [self valueChanged:nil];
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear called");
}`

Comment: I added `viewDidAppear` to `applicationWillEnterForeground` in AppDelegate and that solved the problem. I don't know if this is the right way to do it as I'm new to Objective-C

Comment: I just saw your answer. Calling viewDidAppear yourself is not good practice. You should create a method like "resetSlider" and call it everywhere you need, like in *applicationWillEnterForeground*. Make sure you can still leave the app from another screen (if your app has other screens), and come back without the app crashing. Calling a ViewController's method from the delegate can be dangerous (the ViewController may not exist). Make sure you protect your app from this to happen !

Comment: Thank you for your input, I appreciate it. I wish there was an easier way for viewDidAppear to just fire each time the app enters the foreground though.